# .htaccess redirect to different alias

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect the alias Eg.

http://test.com/mp3 to https://test.com/audio

I had tried this code

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|zip|rar)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mp3$ /audio? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Not work for me . Problem is when i search my site on google and click on any search result it will goes to https://test.com/mp3

Please Help

Thanks
Krishna Karki

Comment: Can you post your htaccess file content so we can see where the problem might be?

Comment: Hi @Dominik i had just added the code which i had used please have a look. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Did you try combining the two if blocks to one? I imagine they might overwrite each other?

Comment: Yes I had tried this also but still not working ...